# Path parameter in API suffix Azure API management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim

Is it possible to create multiple APIs in Azure APIM that contain path parameters. I want to create multiple apis like this:

**Users**
`https://{MyAPI}.azure-api.net/organisations/{orgId}/users`

**EntityTypes**
`https://{MyAPI}.azure-api.net/organisations/{orgId}/entitytypes`

**Workflows**
`https://{MyAPI}.azure-api.net/organisations/{orgId}/workflows`

I need to give different products access to different Apis. eg. One product only has access to Users and UserTypes and the other has access to everything.

Is this possible in Azure APIM?

I tried adding the path parameter in the API URL suffix field but keep getting URL invalid error. I also have not seen any of this in the documentation. (I might be going with this the wrong way)

[image: Image with error]

EDIT:
Updated question layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the below URLs in Azure APIM in the following way-

**Users**  `https://{MyAPI}.azure-api.net/organisations/{orgId}/users`

**EntityTypes**  `https://{MyAPI}.azure-api.net/organisations/{orgId}/entitytypes`

**Workflows**  `https://{MyAPI}.azure-api.net/organisations/{orgId}/workflows`

Initially, I created an API

[image]

Then added ***Users***, ***EntityTypes*** and ***Workflows*** as operations in it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can check the Json file wherein orgid is added as a path parameter.

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0.1",
    "info": {
        "title": "Test API",
        "description": "",
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "servers": [{
        "url": "https://*****.azure-api.net/organisations"
    }],
    "paths": {
        "/{orgId}/users": {
            "get": {
                "summary": "Users",
                "operationId": "users",
                "parameters": [{
                    "name": "orgId",
                    "in": "path",
                    "required": true,
                    "schema": {
                        "type": ""
                    }
                }],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": null
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/{orgId}/entitytypes": {
            "get": {
                "summary": "EntityTypes",
                "operationId": "entitytypes",
                "parameters": [{
                    "name": "orgId",
                    "in": "path",
                    "required": true,
                    "schema": {
                        "type": ""
                    }
                }],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": null
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/{orgId}/workflows": {
            "get": {
                "summary": "Workflows",
                "operationId": "workflows",
                "parameters": [{
                    "name": "orgId",
                    "in": "path",
                    "required": true,
                    "schema": {
                        "type": ""
                    }
                }],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": null
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "securitySchemes": {
            "apiKeyHeader": {
                "type": "apiKey",
                "name": "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",
                "in": "header"
            },
            "apiKeyQuery": {
                "type": "apiKey",
                "name": "subscription-key",
                "in": "query"
            }
        }
    },
    "security": [{
        "apiKeyHeader": []
    }, {
        "apiKeyQuery": []
    }]
}
```

In this way, you can add the path parameters.

Comment: Thanks. I currently have it like that. The problem however is that I need to be able to assign the APIs to different products. If they are all in one then I need to give all products access to all.

Comment: @Febre In that case you can create three different APIs with `https://{MyAPI}.azure-api.net/organisations` and then add the operation in it individually

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin Thanks, but that will mean I need to pay for all three and I will need to setup products in both plus I will need to reference multiple API urls in my product(Web App) 
I think I will need to rethink how my apis are structured. Thanks in any case. 

I will accept the answer as it might help someone else.

Comment: you can also use versions of and API, since each version is basically an own entity and hence can be placed in separate products. Lets say your API is Foo Bar API, you can version it and name a version to basic, and another to premium. Foo Bar API [basic] can then be placed in a different product, have different logic / open api spec, and so on